# Need help for MySQL comparison query

Tags: mysql, select

happy new year!

I have a little problem creating a MySQL query to compare some DB entries.

There is a table named prices which looks like:

```
{id,timestamp,item,priceCustomer1,priceCustomer2,priceCustomer3}
```

sample values:

```
{1,1483453891,"Paper A",2.99,2.70,1.90}
{2,1483453891,"Paper B",1.99,1.70,2.90}
{3,1483453891,"Paper C",4.99,3.70,3.90}
{4,1483453704,"Paper A",2.80,2.70,1.90}
{5,1483453704,"Paper B",1.90,1.75,2.90}
{6,1483453704,"Paper C",4.99,3.70,3.90}
```

There are price information for different items from different moments recognizable on timestamp.
The query should compare the three prices of each items from the last two timestamps and list all entries where at least one price is different.

Is my goal comprehensible?

I tried lot of statements but now I'm desperate and don't know what to try next time.

It would be very nice if somebody could help me.

Thanks so much!
Greetings

edit:

Thanks for the fast replies! First query to get the last two timestamps I tried is this one:

```
SELECT date FROM prices GROUP BY date ORDER BY date DESC limit 2;
```

The others queries I tried aren't there now because of try&error at the mysql console. 
The result I would expect with the sample data would be like this:

```
{1,1483453891,"Paper A",2.99} 
{4,1483453704,"Paper A",2.80}  
{2,1483453891,"Paper B",1.99,1.70} 
{5,1483453704,"Paper B",1.90,1.75}
```

Comment: What statements did you tried already?

Comment: Always show where you are (what's your current SQL statement?) You get more assistance on showing your work.  Also, provide expected results.  Knowing what you expect to see helps clarify your question.  My approach would be to generate 2 data sets 1 for each time period and then join those data-sets together and then use a case statements to compare prices between each for the same item. if a variance exists, list the record.

Comment: And show the results you want from the same data example.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry: Thanks but that's not helpful. I think a CREATE statement for this "small table" is not necessary.

Comment: @xQbert: Thanks for your idea! Could you tell me how to create these two datasets? Maybe do you mean creating two different view?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your idea xQbert... I think I have found the solution:

```
CREATE VIEW oldData AS
SELECT * 
FROM prices 
WHERE date= (SELECT date FROM prices GROUP BY date ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 2     OFFSET 1);

CREATE VIEW newData AS
SELECT * 
FROM prices 
WHERE date= (SELECT date FROM prices GROUP BY date ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1);

SELECT * 
FROM olddata JOIN newdata USING(item) 
WHERE (olddata.priceCustomer1 <> newdata.priceCustomer1) 
OR (olddata.priceCustomer2 <> newdata.priceCustomer2)
OR (olddata.priceCustomer3 <> newdata.priceCustomer3);
```

I think this produces the result, I need. Thank!

Comment: you don't need to Create the views" you could substitute your select statements as inline views replacing the table names oldData and Newdata with `(yourSelectstatement) as oldData` and `(YourSelectStatement) as newData)`  but otherwise yes I think this would achieve what you're after.  This does assume however that the item exists in both data sets.  If an item were to only exist in 1 of the two datasets you would need to use a LEFT JOIN and a union with a right Join as mySQL doesn't support full outer joins. and alter the where to include OR (olddata.item is null or newdata.item is null)`

Answer (score 0):

If there's a chance that the item may not exist on both dates... then you may need to simulate a full outer join and use left/right joins and a union

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM prices 
      WHERE date= (SELECT date 
                   FROM prices 
                   GROUP BY date 
                   ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 2 OFFSET 1)) oldData
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
           FROM prices 
           WHERE date= (SELECT date 
                        FROM prices 
                        GROUP BY date 
                        ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1)) newData
 USING(item) 
WHERE (olddata.priceCustomer1 <> newdata.priceCustomer1) 
   OR (olddata.priceCustomer2 <> newdata.priceCustomer2)
   OR (olddata.priceCustomer3 <> newdata.priceCustomer3)
   OR newData.item is null
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM prices 
      WHERE date= (SELECT date 
                   FROM prices 
                   GROUP BY date 
                   ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 2 OFFSET 1)) oldData
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT * 
           FROM prices 
           WHERE date= (SELECT date 
                        FROM prices 
                        GROUP BY date 
                        ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1)) newData
 USING(item) 
WHERE (olddata.priceCustomer1 <> newdata.priceCustomer1) 
   OR (olddata.priceCustomer2 <> newdata.priceCustomer2)
   OR (olddata.priceCustomer3 <> newdata.priceCustomer3)
   OR oldData.item is null
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! This works great for me.
Have a nice week!